# Javascript get all tags with the same name

Tags: javascript, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
  <Section Id="1" Type="page" Caption="Message Details">
    <Containers>
      <Form Id="General" Caption="General Details" Source="Request" Layout="Fixed">
        <Controls>
          <Control Id="MessageType" Caption="Message Type" Source="Param[@Name = 'MessageType']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="150" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="1" Mandatory="1" DefaultValue="Allert" Action="handleMessageTypeChange()" BreakAfter="0">
            <Member Value="SMS" Caption="SMS"/>
            <Member Value="EMAIL" Caption="EMAIL"/>
            <Member Value="ATOS" Caption="ATOS"/>
            <Member Value="SELF SERVICE" Caption="SELF SERVICE"/>
          </Control>
          <Control Id="Language" Caption="Language" Source="Param[@Name = 'Language']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="100" CaptionWidth="90" ReadOnly="1" BreakAfter="1"/>
          <Control Id="FirstName" Caption="First Name" Source="Param[@Name = 'FirstName']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" DefaultValue="hello"/>
          <Control Id="LastName" Caption="Last Name" Source="Param[@Name = 'LastName']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1"/>
          <Control Id="IMTSI" Caption="IMTSI" Source="Param[@Name = 'IMTSI']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="0"/>
          <Control Id="Mobile" Caption="Mobile" Source="Param[@Name = 'Mobile']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="1"/>
          <Control Id="Email" Caption="Email" Source="Param[@Name = 'Email']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" Mandatory="0"/>
          <Control Id="Subject" Caption="Subject" Source="Param[@Name = 'Subject']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" MaxLen="40" Hidden="1"/>
          <Control Id="Content" Caption="Content" Source="Param[@Name = 'Content']" FieldName="Value" DataType="longstring" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" Height="60" BreakAfter="1" MaxLen="50" Mandatory="1" SeparateBefore="1" SeparateAfter="1"/>
          <Control Id="Sender" Caption="Sender" Source="Param[@Name = 'Sender']" FieldName="Value" DataType="string" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" ReadOnly="1" BreakAfter="1"/>
          <Control Id="Priority" Caption="Priority" Source="Param[@Name = 'Priority']" FieldName="Value" DataType="select" Width="350" CaptionWidth="120" BreakAfter="1" DefaultValue="LOW">
            <Member Value="LOW" Caption="Low" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_blue.png"/>
            <Member Value="MED" Caption="Medium" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_yellow.png"/>
            <Member Value="HIGH" Caption="High" Glyf="../../GUIGenerator_V2/assets/themes/Images/flag_red.png"/>
          </Control>
        </Controls>
      </Form>
    </Containers>
  </Section>
</Module>
```

I'm trying to get all the "Control" tag on the button (with the Captions: Subject, Content, etc.) using JavaScript, how would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).

Here is how to use it:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('Control')
for (var i=0, len = els.length; i<len; i++) {
    els[i] // You have your element.
}
```

Use a debugger to see which properties are available in every `els[i]` object.

Comment: OK, but how could I run on all the elements?

Comment: What are you running this on? A browser?

Comment: `        var els = document.getElementsByTagName('Control');
        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
            alert(els[i].getAttribute("ID"));  // You have your element.
        }`